# In what time ranges do you verify your canary deployments?

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment

I am currently implementing a canary deployment strategy for the services of an

Have you already worked with carary deployments? After which timeframe do you decide to roull out 100%? Which factors do you take into account?

I could not find any experience data for this topic. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This totally depends on the application and amount of traffic. In fact, many apps receive so little traffic that it is not useful to use canary deployment.

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense if one considers fractions rather than absolute amounts of traffic  ie a canary deploy is considered complete when it receives 5% of the steady-state traffic.